# Teleporting to which direction I'm facing using command blocks in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know what commands to put in when, for example, I want to teleport myself into **y=11** *but only when I'm facing north*. and *when I'm facing south* I'll get teleported to **y=-11**

> EDIT: Also, I've seen some threads here that ask almost the same
>   questions here but I got the idea, but what I saw was only if a person
>   was looking at a specific facing coordinate (where they'll use
>   [x_rotation] and [y_rotation].

If you found some threads that ask exactly the same question. It would be highly appreciative if you link me into it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I got it.

Anyhow, The command was simple but hard to implement.

/execute at @e[type=player,x_rotation=**-45..45**,y_rotation=**135..-135**] if block ~ ~-3 ~ minecraft:daylight_detector run tp @p ~ ~5 ~

> adding the two ".." in between the numbers in the x_rotation and
>   y_rotation allows the player to teleport when the player is looking at a direction **BETWEEN -45 to 45 and 135 to -135**